# OBD ii Dataset for collision dectection

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, cars, accelerometer

We are a tech team of an insurance company. My team working on a project to find out faking collision for insurance claims. So we are currently testing 100 of our insurance clients with OBD ii. we just start collecting data. But to progress in our research, we are looking for a tested OBD ii dataset with many parameters. **especially with an accelerometer, gyroscope, and collision occurrence information.**

any suggestions would be appreciated